# How do I prevent godot exports from corrupting?

Tags: godot

This is the second time it happens... the first time I didn't expect it so I lost a lot of work.

I make a project, spend 40-60 hours on it, gives no error, works perfectly on the debugger... I export it multiple times to try it on my phone and my other computer and everything works perfectly.

Then out of a sudden, the game still works in the game engine but the .exe crashes on start and the .apk freezes...

Naturally I have a multiple backups to solve the problem... but for some reason backups from days ago also get corrupted.

Clarification: it doesn't corrupt every single back up file, but like ... I make a back up almost every 15 minutes.... and try the game just as frequently but instead of losing 15 minutes of work when one gets corrupted, I lose a few days.

So magically a backup that was saved on google drive from 15 minutes ago and worked perfectly becomes corrupted as soon as I download it to try it.

Deleting scenes or scripts from the game doesn't fix the issue and even simply importing anything at all from one project that is corrupted to another corrupts the newer project too so my games end up being nothing more than a bunch of useless ingredient lists cause as soon as something get's corrupted I lose days of progress or have to restart everything over again.

Comment: The idea that this corruption can be transferred from one project to another sounds odd to me... You are making backups, but are doing versions control? Can you see at a diff of what changed? - Does removing the .godot folder so Godot recreates it help? - Approaching this from the opposite perspective, check SMART (Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology) on your storage device, it could be starting to fail.

Comment: While I'm sympathetic to the frustration that such problems generate, please note that [Stack Exchange generally doesn't permit expletives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/228147).